# Adding an element to beginning of linked list C

Tags: c, linked-list, pass-by-reference, singly-linked-list, function-definition

I am new to programming and currently trying to figure out linked lists in C. I have created a simple list with three nodes containing the numbers 1, 2 and 3.

```
typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
} Node;

int main() {
    struct Node* head = NULL;
    struct Node* second = NULL;
    struct Node* third = NULL;

    head = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    second = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    third = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    head->data = 1; // assign data in first node
    head->next = second; // Link first node with second node

    second->data = 2; // assign data to second node
    second->next = third;// Link second node with the third node

    third->data = 3; // assign data to third node
    third->next = NULL;
}
```

Next I want to insert a value put in by the user into the beginning of the list using the function add_and_print

```
int num;
printf("Enter number to add to beginning of list: ");
scanf(" %d", &num);

add_and_print(num, head);
```

The function add_and_print looks as follows:

```
void add_and_print(int num, Node* head) {
    Node* new_node;
    new_node = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    new_node->data = num;
    new_node->next= head;
    head = new_node;
    printf("Value inside Function: %d\n", head->data);

}
```

For "Value inside function" I get the value that I previously entered, so far so good. However, after calling the function in main I try to print the head value again

```
add_and_print(num, head);
printf("Value outside function: %d", head->data);
```

and I get 1, the head value I had before applying the function. And when I try to print the whole list I get 123. I can't understand why the changes made by the function don't get saved globally.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Please read the wikipedia page on [linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list)s. There is a nice figure there. Then read the documentation of your compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) which you could invoke as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) and of your debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/))

Comment: Consider returning the `new_node` from the `add_and_print` function. You could assign this value to `head`...

Answer (score 1):

The way you are making changes will not be seen by your caller function since the changes are local to `add_and_print`.

your `add_and_print` should be like this:

either follow case 1:
pass address of `head` as `add_and_print(num, &head)`

```
void add_and_print(int num, Node** head) {
    Node* new_node;
    new_node = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    new_node->data = num;
    new_node->next= *head;
    *head = new_node;
    printf("Value inside Function: %d\n", head->data);

}
```

or follow case 2:
return the new node address after attaching the `head` to the new node

`head = add_and_print(num, head)`

```
Node* add_and_print(int num, Node* head) {
    Node* new_node;
    new_node = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    new_node->data = num;
    new_node->next= head;
    printf("Value inside Function: %d\n", head->data);
    return new_node;
}
```

**NOTE:** Check `malloc` return value before using and `free` the pointers once you are done with it.

Answer (score 1):

The `head` variable inside `main` and the `head` parameter for `add_and_print` are two different variables. So the assignment `head = new_node` inside `add_and_print` will *not* update the `head` variable in `main`.

The only way to update the `head` variable in `main` and to update it there is to return the new value from the `add_and_print` function:

```
Node* add_and_print(int num, Node* head) {
    Node* new_node;
    new_node = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    if (new_node) {
        new_node->data = num;
        new_node->next= head;
        head = new_node;
        printf("Value inside Function: %d\n", head->data);
    }
    return head;
}
```

Inside `main` call this as

```
head = add_and_print(num, head);
```

Note that I have added a minimal amount of error checking and that `add_and_print` will never return `NULL` (and has no way of reporting errors)

As an aside, it is usually a bad idea to let your functions do multiple things. Here the printing may be helpful for debugging, but should not be part of the final function. And as it adds an item in the from you can call it `add_to_front` or `prepend`.

Comment: Claiming “the only way” is overstating your case.  There is another way of achieving the result (and those who are desperate might try tinkering with global variables, but that's not a good idea).

Answer (score 0):

Function parameters are local variables of the function that are initialized by the values of the expressions used as arguments.

So within your function `add_and_print` you are dealing with the function local variable `head` that was initialized by the value of the pointer `head` declared in `main`. Changing the local variable (parameter) `head` within the function does not influence on the original argument.

You have to pass the pointer `head` declared in `main` by reference. In C passing by reference means passing an object indirectly through a pointer to it.

The function can be declared and defined the following way.

```
int add_and_print( Node **head, int num ) 
{
    Node *new_node = malloc( sizeof( struct Node ) );
    int success = new_node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        new_node->data = num;
        new_node->next = *head;
        *head = new_node;
        printf( "Value inside Function: %d\n", head->data );
    }
    else
    {
        puts( "Error. Not enough memory." );
    }

    return success;
}
```

And the function can be called for example like

```
if ( add_and_print( &head, num ) )
{
    printf( "Value outside function: %d\n", head->data );
}
```

Pay attention to that the function should not output any message. It is the caller of the function that decides whether to output a message or not. So it is better to define the function like

```
int add_front( Node **head, int num ) 
{
    Node *new_node = malloc( sizeof( struct Node ) );
    int success = new_node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        new_node->data = num;
        new_node->next = *head;
        *head = new_node;
    }

    return success;
}
```

And in main you can write

```
if ( add_front( &head, num ) )
{
    printf("Value outside function: %d\n", head->data);
}
else
{
    puts( "Error. Not enough memory." );
}
```